# c library defines of int8_t

Tags: c

From stdint.h the following

```
#ifndef int8_t

    typedef signed char int8_t;
    #define int8_t int8_t
    #define INT8_MIN (-128)
    #define INT8_MAX (127)

#endif
```

What does the `#define int8_t int8_t` do or define ?

Comment: It just prevents multiple inclusions of the same definitions (see the `#ifndef int8_t` at the start ?).

Comment: Aside: Code could use a `#if SCHAR_MIN == -128` to insure portability.

Answer (score 1):

It defines `int8_t` as a macro whose existence can be tested with `#ifndef int8_t`, presumably with the intent of preventing `int8_t` from being defined twice.

I don't know *why* it does it this way. It would make more sense to use a single [include guard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) around the entire `<stdint.h>` header.

(In a previous version of this answer, I asserted that the implementation is non-conforming, since it defines `int8_t` as a macro. Doing so is unnecessary, but not invalid. Quoting [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 7.1.3:

> Each identifier with file scope listed in any of the following
>   subclauses (including the future library directions) is reserved for
>   use as a macro name and as an identifier with file scope in the same
>   name space if any of its associated headers is included.

So the identifier `int8_t` is reserved for use as a macro, and the implementation's macro definition is permitted.)

What implementation is this from?